# Cannot protect configuration while locked

Tags: .net, encryption, configuration

This is a follow-up to [Cache password for SQL Server connection as a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567519/cache-password-for-sql-server-connection-as-a-hash) .

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15392/Implementing-Protected-Configuration-With-Windows describes a method for local Windows applications to use protected configurations. However, based on the environment in which my application is designed to run, an installer is not desirable.

I've tried to run the following:

```
        object settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("userSettings/MyApp.Properties.Settings");
        SectionInformation info = ((ConfigurationSection)settings).SectionInformation;
        if (!info.IsProtected)
            info.ProtectSection("DPAPIProtection");
```

at several different times in my WPF application, but each time I do, I get this exception from .NET's SectionInformation.cs in VerifyIsEditable:

```
if (IsLocked) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.Config_cannot_edit_configurationsection_when_locked));
```

So. Is there a way to either (a) run `ProtectSection()` before the configuration is loaded and locked, or (b) at the end of the application after calling `Settings.Default.Save()`, flush the configuration, close and unlock it, and then call `ProtectSection()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it (though I'm not sure why, exactly):

```
        Configuration conf = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration
            (ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
        ClientSettingsSection settings = (ClientSettingsSection)
            conf.GetSection("userSettings/MyApp.Properties.Settings");
        SectionInformation info = settings.SectionInformation;

        if (!info.IsProtected)
        {
            info.ProtectSection("DPAPIProtection");
            info.ForceSave = true;
            conf.Save();
        }
```